# Why do AWS JavaScript SDK calls to DynamoDB fail with native data types?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

When I try to query Amazon DynamoDB using native JavaScript data types it fails (e.g. :zipcode below). For example, the following code fails with `Error while fetching data: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`.

```
import { DynamoDBClient, QueryCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

const client = new DynamoDBClient({});

await client.send(
  new QueryCommand({
    TableName: tableName,
    KeyConditionExpression: "zipcode = :zipcode ",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":zipcode": "11111",
    },
    ConsistentRead: true,
  })
);
```

But the below code works.

```
import { DynamoDBClient, QueryCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

const client = new DynamoDBClient({});

docClient.send(
  new QueryCommand({
    TableName: tableName,
    KeyConditionExpression: "zipcode = :zipcode ",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":zipcode": { "S": "11111" },
    },
    ConsistentRead: true,
  })
);
```

What is this `{ "S": <value> }` syntax and why is it needed?

Comment: your question is not clear? Are you simply wondering why you get no error when you use `":zipcode": {S: "11111"}` rather than `":zipcode": "11111"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second version of the syntax is correct. DynamoDB needs to know what data type you're sending it. The `S` in `{ "S": "1111" }` indicates that you're sending a string. You can see a full list of the data type descriptors [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.LowLevelAPI.html).

Optionally, if you want to use your first syntax, you can use the Document Client.

V3

```
import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import { DynamoDBDocumentClient, QueryCommand } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";

const client = new DynamoDBClient({});
const docClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);

docClient.send(
  new QueryCommand({
    TableName: tableName,
    KeyConditionExpression: "zipcode = :zipcode",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":zipcode": "11111",
    },
    ConsistentRead: true,
  })
);
```

V2

```
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk";

var params = {
  TableName: "Table",
  KeyConditionExpression: "zipcode = :zipcode",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":zipcode": "11111",
  }
};

var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

documentClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err);
   else console.log(data);
});
```

The [Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/javascript_3_dynamodb_code_examples.html) for the JS SDK has multiple examples showcasing this syntax.

Comment: One more thing the data returned looks like:
Item: {
  zipCode: { S: '11111' },
  councilId: { S: 'C10001' },
  streetData: { L: [ [Object], [Object] ] }
}
How to get the data without the data types like S:, L: etc. ? For reading i am using v2

Comment: I'm not sure why you would use V2 in one place and V3 in another, I would caution against that. To my knowledge, V2 does not have an equivalent to lib-dynamodb. You'll have to handle the datatypes yourself. If you found the answer helpful, please accept it!

Comment: A colleague corrected me. It does exist :) 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html

Comment: Thanks @Corey. Can you please point to unit test for DynamoDB query using v2 sdk?

Comment: @Spartacus I cannot, as they do not exist :)